# Hive "ESCAPED BY" Clause escapes default NULL values

Tags: null, hive, escaping, sqoop

I have a table with varchar(1),varchar(2), varchar(12) and int columns.  The values are "Sqooped" from an external database and NULLs are defined as "\N" with

```
--null-string '\N' --null-non-string '\N'
```

Sqoop is instructed to escape-by "\" and so the null values are also escaped and are written as "\\N" instead of "\N".
The values appear in the varchar(1) column as "\", or in the varchar(2) column they are "\", they are "\N" in the varchar(3) column, but are correctly NULL in the int or any other type column.
I have instructed Hive in the create table that the escaped BY character is "\", but that hasn't helped.

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ESCAPED BY '\'
```

Short of choosing a different NULL identifier, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Oh, Maybe I should try a different escape character in Hive and sqoop.  Anyone have a good escape character to use?